# When VPN is on in WSL2, how can I ping windows from WSL2

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

## windows(host) does not use VPN

When VPN is off, I can ping my windows(host) from both WSL2 and docker container but when it's on

all settings are default

cmd ipconfig

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.48.1
```

WSL2 $ ip route

```
default via 172.27.48.1 dev eth0
172.27.48.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.51.31
```

If I need to provide more information, please let me know

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by adding route manually. After that I can ping windows even when the container is connected to VPN

from inside of container:

```
$ ip route add 192.168.1.100 via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0
```

in my case:

192.168.1.100 is the target NIC(destination)

172.17.0.1 is gateway which is you can find by run ip route inside container

hopefully it helps :D